# Intranet GIS app with JS web app builder?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, web-service, arcgis-web-appbuilder

Is there a work-around for building an intranet GIS app with ESRI JS web app builder (without sharing data to the public)?  Does it mean that I have to create a web map in ArcGIS com or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Akis,

I think the answer to "Q3" on the blog post [Clarifying 3 questions about Web AppBuilder for ArcGIS](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/04/06/clarifying-3-questions-about-web-appbuilder-for-arcgis/) probably best answers your question.

Just an added note that you can certainly author a Web Map that does not share data to the public, and then use Web AppBuilder to build an app based on that web map. Either:

- create a web map that contains a [Hosted Web Layer](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/hosted-web-layers.htm) that is not shared to the public, or
- create a web map where you "[add layers from the web](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/add-layers.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_A82A515232CB4672838FEB9FCF8E76D8)" referencing internally hosted ArcGIS Server Services. A reference to the data (the url) is stored in the webmap, but your data is still protected behind your network firewall.